# Is it possible that a gravitational wave of spacetime hit the solar system?

Tags: spacetime, solar-system, gravitational-waves, ligo

I went (on vacation) to the beach, The sea was very calm (just like solar system) There was one person in a fishing boat, Suddenly a huge wave came to shore...

Is it possible that a gravitational wave of space - time hit the solar system in a same way?.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are experimental projects ([LIGO](http://www.ligo.caltech.edu/), and friends) to detect large [gravitational waves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave) from the collisions of neutron stars and black holes with other dense massive objects, but the mechanism of such waves in no way resembles waves breaking on the beach: neither in mechanism nor in mathematics.

If you have some space cycles, [Einstein@Home](http://einstein.phys.uwm.edu/) is a [BOINC](http://boinc.berkeley.edu/wiki/Main_Page) project.